# Only solr or with Mysql

Tags: mysql, solr

I want to use solr for my search index.What confuse me is ,should i put most the data fields in solr ,or only search for the id ,then get the data from Mysql,please help.Which is faster,better

Comment: it depends, for faster retrieval of results storing in Solr would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Question in 2010 an decided to take Solr as a search index only to get a list of IDs in the first step an read the data from MySQL related to the IDs in the 2nd step.
That works fine in an Environment with 20 million docs.

During an reconstruction of the whole application in 2014, we decided to additional store the data in Solr (not only indexing) in order to fetch the whole docs during a search, so that the MySQL connect is not necessary anymore.

We are talking about an Web - Application with only max. 1-3 thousand parallel users and there is absolutely no perceived difference in application speed between the version from 2010 and 2014.

But there are some benefits, if you take the documents from Solr, not MySql.

The application code is a bit cleaner.
You only need one connect to get the data....
But: the main reason, why we begin to store the document in solr is: we needed to use the highlighting feature. This will only work well, if you store the docs on solr and fetches them from solr too.
Btw: there is no change in search performance if you store the docs or not.

The disadvantage is, that you have to hold the data twice:
1.) in MySQL as the base dataset and
2.) in Solr for your application.

And: if you have very big documents, solr probably is not the right tool to serve that kind of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the data into Solr will absolutely be faster: you are saving yourself from having to make two queries, and also you are removing the need for a slow piece of code (PHP or whatever) to bridge the gap between these two where you pull out the id from solr and then query mysql. Alternatively you could put everything into MySQL, which would be of comparable speed. i.e. choose a technology suiting your needs best, but don't mix unnecessarily for performance reasons. A good comparison when you might want to use Solr vs MySQL can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960952/when-to-consider-solr).